# Digi Chat (V4.1) crashes when I close PuTTY

Tags: chat, putty

I am running a VPS, CentOS 6 with a copy of digi chat 4.1 on it. The chat runs fine, if I open putty and run the usual start up code:

```
    # java -cp Server.zip com.diginet.digichat.server.ChatServer
```

The second I close PuTTY, the chat turns off. Or after the initialization sequence Digi Chat runs after that command, if it gives me a new prompt line (usually it doesn't, but for example copying a piece of code cause it to), the chat turned off.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As root run:

```
java -cp Server.zip com.diginet.digichat.server.ChatServer &
```

If you installed using the InstallAnywhere launcher, there is also a system service you can start in `/etc/init.d/`.